# EF Core Linq Query Syntax

Tags: linq, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.0

I'm trying to replicate a view inside EF.  The original view used a UNION operator so have split my initial query here in tow to better match.  Having some issues working out my syntax.  I am trying to query the groups, get their primary contact details.  Also get all vehicles and their linked groups.  I believe I have specified the ContactLink requirement correctly in the first query.

```
[BindProperty]
public IList<OrgChartNode> OrgChartNodes { get; set; }

public JsonResult OnGet(string OrgCode)
{
            IList<OrgChartNode> OrgChartGroups = _db.Groups
                                                .Include(g => g.ContactLinks)
                                                    .ThenInclude(gtc => gtc.Contact)
                                                .Include(g => g.Organisation)
                                                .Where(g => g.OrgCode.Equals(OrgCode))
                                                .Where(g => g.ContactLinks.Any(cl => cl.LinkTypeId == 1))
                                                .Select(g => new OrgChartNode
                                                {
                                                    Id = g.Id,
                                                    Name = g.Name,
                                                    TierId = g.TierId,
                                                    ParentGroupId = g.ParentGroupId,
                                                    OrgName = g.Organisation.Name,
                                                    OrgCode = g.OrgCode,
                                                    ContactName = g.ContactLinks.**Contact**.Name,
                                                    ContactEmail = g.ContactLinks.**Contact**.Phone,
                                                    ContactPhone = g.ContactLinks.**Contact**.Email,
                                                    ContactId = g.ContactLinks.**Contact**.ContactId,
                                                })
                                                .OrderByDescending(g => g.TierId)
                                                .ThenBy(g => g.Name)
                                                .AsNoTracking()
                                                .ToList();

        IList<OrgChartNode> OrgChartUnits = _db.Units
                                                .Include(u => u.GroupLinks)
                                                .Include(u => u.Organisation)
                                                .Where(u => u.OrgCode.Equals(OrgCode))
                                                .Select(u => new OrgChartNode
                                                {
                                                    Id = u.NodeId,
                                                    Name = u.Name,
                                                    TierId = 0,
                                                    ParentGroupId = u.GroupLinks.**GroupId**,
                                                    OrgName = u.Organisation.Name,
                                                    OrgCode = u.OrgCode,
                                                    ContactName = "",
                                                    ContactEmail = "",
                                                    ContactPhone = "",
                                                    ContactId = 0,
                                                })
                                                .OrderBy(u => u.Name)
                                                .AsNoTracking()
                                                .ToList();

        OrgChartNodes = OrgChartGroups.Concat(OrgChartUnits)
                                .ToList();

        return new JsonResult(OrgChartNodes);
}
```

The four Contact fields have been marked wih **.  They have red intellisense lines in Visual Studio. Looks like it cat follow to Contact, despite it being `ThenInclude()` above. So does the GroupId in the second query.  Hovering over the acronym/aliases tells me they appear to be the correct classes.

[image: Table Diagram]

Listed below are the three data classes.  You can see the Navigation properties.  Are they configured correctly?

How can I include the contact details in my `.Select()` call?

**Group.cs**

```
[Table("Report_Group")]
public class Group
{
    [Key, Required, Column("GroupId")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required, MaxLength(5)]
    public string OrgCode  { get; set; }

    [Required, MaxLength(100)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int TierId { get; set; }

    public int? ParentGroupId { get; set; }

    public int? CostCenter { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int ExcludeFromAlertStats { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int GroupTypeId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ParentGroupId")]
    public virtual Group Parent { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("OrgCode")]
    public virtual Organisation Organisation { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("TierId")]
    public virtual Tier Tier { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("GroupTypeId")]
    public virtual GroupType GroupType { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("GroupId")]
    public virtual IList<GroupToUnitLink> UnitLinks { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("GroupId")]
    public virtual IList<GroupToContactLink> ContactLinks { get; set; }
}
```

**GroupToContactLink.cs**

This classes key is set using fluent in `OnModelCreating()` as it is a composite key.

```
[Table("Report_Link_Group_to_Contact")]
public class GroupToContactLink
{
    public GroupToContactLink()
    {
    }

    public GroupToContactLink(int contactId, int groupId, int linkTypeId)
    {
        this.ContactId = contactId;
        this.GroupId = groupId;
        this.LinkTypeId = linkTypeId;
    }

    [Required]
    public int ContactId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int GroupId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int LinkTypeId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ContactId")]
    public virtual Contact Contact { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("GroupId")]
    public virtual Group Group { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("LinkTypeId")]
    public virtual ContactLinkType LinkType { get; set; }

}
```

**Contact.cs**

```
[Table("Report_Contact")]
public class Contact
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Primary Key for Contact in the database
    /// </summary>
    [Key, Column("ContactId")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Foreign Key indicating <see cref="Data.Organisation"/>
    /// </summary>
    [Required, StringLength(5)]
    public string OrgCode { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Name of Contact
    /// </summary>
    [Required, StringLength(100)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Phone number of contact.  Needs to be in +614 format for SMS to work
    /// </summary>
    [StringLength(12)]
    public string Phone { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Email Address for Contact
    /// </summary>
    [StringLength(255), EmailAddress]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Navigation property to <see cref="Data.Organisation"/>
    /// </summary>
    [ForeignKey("OrgCode")]
    public virtual Organisation Organisation { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("ContactId")]
    public virtual IList<GroupToContactLink> GroupLinks { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: So Whats your question?

Comment: `.ContactLinks.First().Contact`?

Comment: ...and you don't actually need any of those `.Include()` and `.ThenInclude()` calls.

Comment: I think that solved it for me @bricelam however I can't test it, as app currently tanks.  Make an answer so I can accept.  Feel free to checkout my other problem at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50575259/asp-net-core-2-1-crashing-due-to-model-inverseproperty