# Asp.net core 2.1 crashing due to model InverseProperty

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.0, ef-core-2.0

My site is crashing on load with an extremely long unhandled exception in System.Reflection on the first call to the DbContext.

Using ef-core 2.1 rc1

```
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: type
   at System.Reflection.IntrospectionExtensions.GetTypeInfo(Type type)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.InversePropertyAttributeConvention.ConfigureInverseNavigation(InternalEntityTypeBuilder entityTypeBuilder, MemberInfo navigationMemberInfo, InternalEntityTypeBuilder targetEntityTypeBuilder, InversePropertyAttribute attribute)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.InversePropertyAttributeConvention.Apply(InternalEntityTypeBuilder entityTypeBuilder, PropertyInfo navigationPropertyInfo, Type targetClrType, InversePropertyAttribute attribute)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.NavigationAttributeEntityTypeConvention`1.Apply(InternalEntityTypeBuilder entityTypeBuilder)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.ImmediateConventionScope.OnEntityTypeAdded(InternalEntityTypeBuilder entityTypeBuilder)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.RunVisitor.VisitOnEntityTypeAdded(OnEntityTypeAddedNode node)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.OnEntityTypeAddedNode.Accept(ConventionVisitor visitor)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.ConventionVisitor.Visit(ConventionNode node)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.ConventionVisitor.VisitConventionScope(ConventionScope node)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.ConventionBatch.Run()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.ConventionBatch.Dispose()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.RelationshipDiscoveryConvention.DiscoverRelationships(InternalEntityTypeBuilder entityTypeBuilder)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.RelationshipDiscoveryConvention.Apply(InternalEntityTypeBuilder entityTypeBuilder)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.ImmediateConventionScope.OnEntityTypeAdded(InternalEntityTypeBuilder entityTypeBuilder)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.OnEntityTypeAdded(InternalEntityTypeBuilder entityTypeBuilder)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.Model.AddEntityType(EntityType entityType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.Model.AddEntityType(Type type, ConfigurationSource configurationSource)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.InternalModelBuilder.Entity(TypeIdentity& type, ConfigurationSource configurationSource, Boolean throwOnQuery)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.InternalModelBuilder.Entity(Type type, ConfigurationSource configurationSource, Boolean throwOnQuery)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.InversePropertyAttributeConvention.Apply(InternalEntityTypeBuilder entityTypeBuilder, PropertyInfo navigationPropertyInfo, Type targetClrType, InversePropertyAttribute attribute)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.NavigationAttributeEntityTypeConvention`1.Apply(InternalEntityTypeBuilder entityTypeBuilder)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.ImmediateConventionScope.OnEntityTypeAdded(InternalEntityTypeBuilder entityTypeBuilder)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.OnEntityTypeAdded(InternalEntityTypeBuilder entityTypeBuilder)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.Model.AddEntityType(EntityType entityType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.Model.AddEntityType(Type type, ConfigurationSource configurationSource)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.InternalModelBuilder.Entity(TypeIdentity& type, ConfigurationSource configurationSource, Boolean throwOnQuery)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.InternalModelBuilder.Entity(Type type, ConfigurationSource configurationSource, Boolean throwOnQuery)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ModelBuilder.Entity(Type type)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelCustomizer.FindSets(ModelBuilder modelBuilder, DbContext context)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.RelationalModelCustomizer.FindSets(ModelBuilder modelBuilder, DbContext context)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelCustomizer.Customize(ModelBuilder modelBuilder, DbContext context)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.RelationalModelCustomizer.Customize(ModelBuilder modelBuilder, DbContext context)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelSource.CreateModel(DbContext context, IConventionSetBuilder conventionSetBuilder, IModelValidator validator)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelSource.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.<GetModel>b__1()
   at System.Lazy`1.ViaFactory(LazyThreadSafetyMode mode)
   at System.Lazy`1.ExecutionAndPublication(LazyHelper executionAndPublication, Boolean useDefaultConstructor)
   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelSource.GetModel(DbContext context, IConventionSetBuilder conventionSetBuilder, IModelValidator validator)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.CreateModel()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.get_Model()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.EntityFrameworkServicesBuilder.<>c.<TryAddCoreServices>b__7_1(IServiceProvider p)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitFactory(FactoryCallSite factoryCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite scopedCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite scopedCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_DbContextDependencies()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_InternalServiceProvider()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_DbContextDependencies()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_Model()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet`1.get_EntityType()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet`1.get_EntityQueryable()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.AsNoTracking[TEntity](IQueryable`1 source)
   at Ctrack.ReportGroups.Pages.IndexModel.OnGetAsync() in C:\Users\lukem\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\Ctrack.ReportGroups\Ctrack.ReportGroups\Pages\Index.cshtml.cs:line 34
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Internal.ExecutorFactory.NonGenericTaskHandlerMethod.Execute(Object receiver, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Internal.PageActionInvoker.InvokeHandlerMethodAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Internal.PageActionInvoker.InvokeNextPageFilterAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Internal.PageActionInvoker.Rethrow(PageHandlerExecutedContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Internal.PageActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Internal.PageActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeNextResourceFilter()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.MigrationsEndPointMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.DatabaseErrorPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.DatabaseErrorPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

The issue may be related to the configuration of Inverse Properties (based on the 2nd at statement)

**Group**

Last 2 fields are inverse

```
[Table("Report_Group")]
public class Group
{
    [Key, Required, Column("GroupId")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required, MaxLength(5)]
    public string OrgCode  { get; set; }

    [Required, MaxLength(100)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int TierId { get; set; }

    public int? ParentGroupId { get; set; }

    public int? CostCenter { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int ExcludeFromAlertStats { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int GroupTypeId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ParentGroupId")]
    public virtual Group Parent { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("OrgCode")]
    public virtual Organisation Organisation { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("TierId")]
    public virtual Tier Tier { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("GroupTypeId")]
    public virtual GroupType GroupType { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("GroupId")]
    public virtual IList<GroupToUnitLink> UnitLinks { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("GroupId")]
    public virtual IList<GroupToContactLink> ContactLinks { get; set; }
}
```

**GroupToContactLink**

Many to Many link table.  No `InverseProperty`'s. Included for reference

```
[Table("Report_Link_Group_to_Contact")]
public class GroupToContactLink
{
    public GroupToContactLink()
    {
    }

    public GroupToContactLink(int contactId, int groupId, int linkTypeId)
    {
        this.ContactId = contactId;
        this.GroupId = groupId;
        this.LinkTypeId = linkTypeId;
    }

    [Required]
    public int ContactId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int GroupId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int LinkTypeId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ContactId")]
    public virtual Contact Contact { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("GroupId")]
    public virtual Group Group { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("LinkTypeId")]
    public virtual ContactLinkType LinkType { get; set; }

}
```

**GroupToUnitLink**

Many to Many link table.  No `InverseProperty`'s.  Included for reference

```
[Table("Report_Link_Group_to_Unit")]
public class GroupToUnitLink
{
    [Required]
    public int NodeId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int GroupId { get; set; }

    public GroupToUnitLink()
    { }

    public GroupToUnitLink(int nodeId, int groupId)
    {
        this.NodeId = nodeId;
        this.GroupId = groupId;
    }

    [ForeignKey("NodeId")]
    public virtual Unit Unit { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("GroupId")]
    public virtual Group Group { get; set; }

}
```

**Contact**

Also has an InverseProperty

```
[Table("Report_Contact")]
public class Contact
{
    [Key, Column("ContactId")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required, StringLength(5)]
    public string OrgCode { get; set; }

    [Required, StringLength(100)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [StringLength(12)]
    public string Phone { get; set; }

    [StringLength(255), EmailAddress]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("OrgCode")]
    public virtual Organisation Organisation { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("ContactId")]
    public virtual IList<GroupToContactLink> GroupLinks { get; set; }
}
```

Are these inverse properties configured correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The work around was to remove the `[InverseProperty()]` annotations from the navigation collections, and add the following to the `OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)` definition

```
    builder
        .Entity<GroupToContactLink>()
        .HasOne(gtc => gtc.Group)
        .WithMany(g => g.ContactLinks);

    builder
        .Entity<GroupToContactLink>()
        .HasOne(gtc => gtc.Contact)
        .WithMany(c => c.GroupLinks);

    builder
        .Entity<GroupToUnitLink>()
        .HasOne(gtc => gtc.Group)
        .WithMany(g => g.UnitLinks);

    builder
        .Entity<GroupToUnitLink>()
        .HasOne(gtc => gtc.Unit)
        .WithMany(c => c.GroupLinks);
```

Comment: Yes I had the same issue, had to remove the InverseProperty annotations and specify the foreign keys in onModelCreating

Answer (score 14):

Your problem is that the inverse property isn't the field on the GroupToContactLink class that references the Contact class.

```
[InverseProperty("ContactId")] // Wrong: don't use the field
```

But it is the navigation property on the class GroupToContactLink that references the Contact class.

```
[InverseProperty("Contact")] // Correct: use the navigation property
```

Comment: can also use the nameof operator:  `[InverseProperty(nameof(GroupToContactLink.Contact))]`