# EF Core Join using Include but ForeignKey is not Primary Key on the other table

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.2

I am trying to relate my Tables with ForeignKey and PrimaryKey on the other end. But now i will be using a ForeignKey which is not the primary for the said table. I was using **[InverseProperty]** but i think there's a bug with it since i've been looking around for hours already and all of them says the same thing about it.

Documents Table:

```
public class Document
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int DocumentId { get; set; }
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }
    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
    public int AuthorId { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public virtual User Author { get; set; }
}
```

Users

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public int AuthUserId { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    [ForeignKey("AuthorId")]
    public virtual Document Document { get; set; }
}
```

Context:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasOne(u => u.Document)
            .WithMany("AuthorId");
        });
```

I am trying to use the solution they [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50575259/asp-net-core-2-1-crashing-due-to-model-inverseproperty), but no luck.

Any help would really be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: A user will have multiple documents, is not it? Please this clear.

Comment: Yes. A user can have multiple Documents. I will be trying now your answer and i have a good feeling about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But now i will be using a ForeignKey which is not the primary for the said table.

To do this you can use EF Core [Alternate Keys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/alternate-keys) feature. But first correct your model class set up as follows: (As you said a `User` will have multiple `Document`)

```
public class Document
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int DocumentId { get; set; }
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }
    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
    public int AuthorId { get; set; }

    public User Author { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public int AuthUserId { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }


    public ICollection<Document> Documents { get; set; }
}
```

Then in the `Fluent API` configuration as follows:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Document>()
        .HasOne(p => p.Author)
        .WithMany(b => b.Documents)
        .HasForeignKey(p => p.AuthorId)
        .HasPrincipalKey(b => b.AuthUserId); // <-- here you are specifying `AuthUserId` as `PrincipalKey` in the relation which is not primary key
```

Comment: Is it giving me a broken JSON data (a single square bracket, nothing more). The way i use on calling the Documents is this. `_dcmsContext.Documents
                    .Include(d => d.DocumentCategory)
                    .Include(d => d.DocumentVersions)
                    .Include(d => d.Author)`

Comment: @Siege21x This is not related to here. This is a separate problem for eager loading data and proxy creation. Give me remote access with team viewer I am fixing this.

Comment: @Siege21x Follow this also :https://stackoverflow.com/a/54633487/5928070

Comment: Easy man. I just finished testing. And yes i am grateful for the help. Thanks!

Comment: But the problem now is when i Use my eager loading above. It pulls all documents with the Authors. Which is correct. But then inside that "Author" object it also pulls all the documents related to the Author itself.

Comment: It's just that i have to do multiple things for me to be able to tests everything.

Comment: Great to hear! Welcome! :)

Comment: I think i would also change the subject a little bit for other people who's also using inverse property to have a work around.

Comment: Yes! What you said is called proxy creation. I shall give you another link related to this. Now I am outside of my computer.

Comment: In summary you cannot stop EF proxy creation!