# One-to-many relationship on custom columns

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have two models that I'd like to specify a one-to-many relationship between, but I can't seem to get it to work.  Here are the models:

```cs
    public class Apple
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int ThingId { get; set; }

        public List<Banana> Bananas { get; set; }
    }
    public class Banana
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int ThingId { get; set; }
 
        [ForeignKey("ThingId")]
        public Apple Apple { get; set; }
    }
```

As you can see, both class `Apple` and class `Banana` have a column in them called `ThingId` and that's how I'd like to join the associations together.  This is a legacy DB so I can't change the column names.  However, when I run a query like this, I don't get an array of `B` objects back even though I know they exist.

```cs
var thing = _context.Apples.Include(a => a.Bananas).FirstOrDefault();
// thing - properly populated but the "Bananas" association is null
```

Any ideas on how I can get this to work properly using a custom column like this (preferably without fluent syntax since I prefer attributes, but not a big deal if that's necessary).

Thanks!

**Edit:**
The link in the answer below by Rafi did the trick.  Here's what I ending up using via the Fluent API.

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Banana>()
        .HasOne(b => b.Apple)
        .WithMany(a => a.Bananas)
        .HasForeignKey(a => a.ThingId)
        .HasPrincipalKey(b => b.ThingId);
}
```

Comment: `@jewnbug97` see my update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try modifying your data models as in the following example:

```cs
public class Apple
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<Banana> Bananas { get; set; }
}

public class Banana
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Apple")]
    public int AppleId { get; set; }

    public Apple Apple { get; set; }
}
```

**Update:**

If `ThingId` is not a primary key consider using `GroupJoin` as below:

```
_context.Apples.GroupJoin(
  bana_context.Bananas,
  apple => apple.ThingId,
  banana => banana.ThingId,
  (apple, bananas) =>
  {
    apple.bananas = bananas.ToList();
    return apple;
  }
)
```

Comment: Hi!  Thanks for the suggestion, but I have no “AppleId” column in the DB for that table so that won’t work.  I only have a “ThingId” column in both tables that I need to join against.

Comment: Yeah, I know that I can access the data through a query, but I was hoping to be able to access it directly through the one-to-many relationship distinction like any other model: `_context.Apples.Include(a => a.Bananas)`.

Comment: `@jewnbug97` you don't have one to many relationship since thingId is not apple's primaryKey

Comment: Yes, but I figured that I could still use EF attributes to link the models together since they have a column that can join them perfectly fine.  Maybe that's not the case though?

Comment: please take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54799285/ef-core-join-using-include-but-foreignkey-is-not-primary-key-on-the-other-table

Comment: that answer in that link worked!  Thanks so much!  Would you like to add that to your answer and then I'll mark it as correct?

Answer (score 1):

Given your scenario, we're going to have to set some few Constraints in order to get the relationship to work. In this case, each apple has a `unique key` called `Id`, which would be a feasible property to use as foreign key to `Apple` related entities. But SQL does allow other columns to be used as foreign keys provided that they are unique for each row, which is `Apple` in your case.

So to achieve this let's look at your given code:

```
public class Apple
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ThingId { get; set; }
    public List<Banana> Bananas { get; set; }
}
public class Banana
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ThingId { get; set; }
    public Apple Apple { get; set; }
}
```

From your code, we'll have to make `ThingId` uniquer for every `Apple`. So let's configure that with Fluent API:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Apple>()
    .HasIndex(ux=>ux.ThingId)
    .IsUnique()
    .Isclustered(false);
```

Then, with continue to configure the one-to-many relationship with fluend API:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Apple>()
   .HasMany(apple => apple.Bananas)
   .WithOne(banana => banana.Apple)
   .HasForeignKey(banana => banana.ThingId)
   .Isrequired(false)
   .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade); // You can set the DeleteBehavior here
```

An then your relationship will be set correctly.

---

**Conclusion**

Let's recap, A `ForeignKey` has to be a unique key from the foreign entity. I always recommend you to use FluentAPI for configuring your relationships, because you have control over many attributes of that relationship.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  I don't however have an `AppleId` column on banana, instead I have a `ThingId` column on both the `Apple` and `Banana` model that I need to connect on.

Comment: OH Man, let me apologize. I didn't pay attention to that earlier and what I did was copy the snipped from the market answer because I assumed it was the initial code you provided. That's what happens when you do things in hurry.

Comment: However, I have just updated my answer above. You are more than welcome to try it out to see if it'll help you keep the same entity structure like in question that changing the properties as suggested on the marked answer.